# How to do bulk upsert operation in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Am syncing my mongo DB data to snowflake on a daily basis using a node js script. So if a row is already existing in snowflake, then I want to replace that row with the new data, or if the row doesn't exist in snowflake then I want to insert a new row.
Also, I want to do this for a lot of data.

So is there any way to do bulk upsert in snowflake? If not, then what will be the optimal way to achieve this?

The table may have millions of rows and possibly go to billions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical use case for a `merge` statement. You can see the documentation for merge here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

Using a merge statement for billions of rows can lead to some [high-churn tables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-storage-considerations.html#managing-costs-for-large-high-churn-tables) so it isn't ideal. It could be better if you can append to the table only and figure out the latest record with a select statement.

Comment: Ok so you are saying, I will push the rows into a staging table and then use merge to push that data to the real table. right?

The merge statement won't be for billions of rows, I till be around some millions (10 - 15) (each day).

Comment: Yep, that's the usual pattern for situations like this. Append into some staging area then merge into the final table.

Answer (score 1):

You can bulk copy your data into a staging table then use [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html) feature in snowflake.